# Powershell -match operator issue

Tags: powershell

I've written a script that compares two strings, both of which are path names.  The first is the full path to a file and the second is a higher level path.  I've replaced spaces and backslashes with underscores.

The variables are assigned correctly such as

```
$full = "__server_department_project_file.txt"
$part = "__server_department_"
```

The script uses

```
$testformatch = $full -match $part
```

In one of my environments this works perfectly (returning TRUE when appropriate).  In another completely separate environment this fails constantly (*always* returns FALSE).

In the failing domain, when I type these things out manually it returns TRUE as expected, but the script always returns FALSE.  I've added a testing line that displays the comparisons, copied those results dumped to the screen and manually cut and pasted them into variables in ps command line directly - and those return TRUE.

I'm at a complete loss for what might be causing this.  Are there special characters or rules about -match that may be coming into play?  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What's different about those environments?

Comment: Casing issues? Culture issues?

Comment: A fine question that I have been unable to identify.  There must be something, but within the limited scope of the script, nothing I can tell.  Same version of powershell.  are there others I should consider?

Comment: Trailing white space issue?

Comment: Compare the results using both `-imatch` and `-cmatch` to see if it's a casing issue.

Comment: How do you actually assign the strings? I'm guessing that you don't type out a string literal in the script.

Comment: have you considered using `$full -match [regex]::escape($part)` instead of replacing backslashes and spaces?

Comment: the strings are identical from a case perspective.  The variables are assigned in a nested foreach loop looking at $records in two csv files.  I can see that the variables are being assigned correctly.  I added a write-host "matching $full with $path : $testformatch" to show each comparison ... all returning FALSE

Comment: "have you considered using $full -match [regex]::escape($part)"  I had not but will moving forward.

Comment: Two CSV files... are they both encoded the same? Could you be picking up hidden characters due to file encoding? Are you comparing the exact same files in both environments, or are you comparing files that are generated using (supposedly) the same process on different computers?

Comment: I would recommend dumping the variable like this to see that they actually contain the intended chars. PS C:\> $fullchararray = $full.ToCharArray();
PS C:\> Foreach ($e in $fullchararray) {
Write-Host $e ([System.String]::Format("{0:X}", [System.Convert]::ToUInt32($e)))
 }

_ 5F
_ 5F
s 73
e 65
r 72
v 76
e 65
r 72
_ 5F
d 64
e 65....